# how to get os.getenviron.get variable with space in it?

Tags: python, macos

So i've created an enviroment variable for a specific path on my MacOS computer. The path has a space in it and looks like this `/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support` . I can get this path successfully from my terminal by wrapping quotation marks around it like `"$variable"`.

However if I from terminal type it without the quotation marks `$variable` then it just returns `/Users/myUser/Library/Application` which is an issue, because then it doesn't find the folder I need.

This is what I have an issue with in python3 also.

```
datadir_path = os.environ.get("variable")
```

returns `/Users/myUser/Library/Application` , which is again an issue because it's missing the last part of the path due to the space in it.

How do I overcome this and get the correct path with `os.environt.get`?

Comment: If you didn't quote the parameter expansion, you didn't set the variable correctly. There's nothing you can do from inside Python to retrieve a value that doesn't exist.

Comment: I did try in my .bash_profile adding `export variable="/Users/myUser/Library/Application\ Support"` with quotation marks around it, but it doesn't change anything. It still prints the value without the string after the space.

Comment: Work as expected: `variable="/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support" python3 -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('variable'))"` → `/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support`

Comment: Have you sourced your bash profile? If you run `export variable="/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support"` in your terminal and then start python (with `python` in terminal) and then run `import os` and `os.environ['variable']` does it work?

Comment: Yes, I've just found the same as @KlausD.

Comment: You guys are right, it works with quotation marks around it. I tried before, but I guess I forgot to source it that one time. My bad and thanks for the help! I'll remember in the future to always add quotation marks around my variables.

Comment: Do you want to write your own answer?

Comment: @ColeRobertson You can have it if you fancy like it? I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include quotes around `$variable` when you export it, and remember to `source` your `.bash_profile`, or restart your `terminal` before you can access `$variable` from `python`.

So add `export variable="/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support"` to `.bash_profile` then run:

```
$ source .bash_profile
$ python
>>>import os
>>> os.environ.get("variable")
"/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support"
>>>
```